# How do I link a local computer file with the entire folder chain in php include()? (like C:\folder\thumbnails.php instead of thumbnails.php)

Tags: php, include

So, let me try to explain:

My website system, which includes a  gigantic list of all the php files that link each other in a complicated linking system to make a single website, is getting out of hand. I can't figure out a way to put a certain type of php files (like, for example, a folder within the main folder below that includes all the posts of a particular category) because then those php files inside the additional folder can't link to the php files outside of that folder.

For the purpose of demonstrating the problem, I created a file with the path Acer(C:)/xampp/htdocs/Demonstration/Photography/photos.php, and I had another php file in the path Acer(C:)/xampp/htdocs/Demonstration/index.php.

My index.php file has:

```
<?php 
include("Photography/photos.php") 
?>

<p>Hello, this is text from index.php</p>
```

My photos.php file has:

```
<p>Hello, this is text from photos.php</p>
```

Clearly, index.php can link photos.php because they share the same parent folder ("Demonstration" folder): (this is what index.php looks like)
[image]

However, I can't find a way to link index.php ONTO photos.php (the other way around) because index.php isn't sharing the same parent folder as photos.php (it isn't in the "Photography" folder, it is OUTSIDE that folder)

So, is there a way to link the php file using the entire pathway of the index.php file and place it in photos.php so it works? (Acer(C:)/xampp/htdocs/Demonstration/index.php) Or, is there another solution to my problem that prevents me from organizing my php files and forces me to put them all in one folder? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To navigate to parent folders

**Folder above**

```
//using .. will navigate to the previous folder.
include("../index.php");

//repeat to keep traversing back
include("../../../index.php"); //would take you back three (3) folders
```

Comment: I tried include("../index.php"); and it showed an error "Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\Demonstration\Photography\photos.php on line 2". Line 2 was where the include function was for photos.php. It's supposed to go back a folder to index.php but it's doing something else...

Comment: That sounds like something is causing your script to take too long. Try oversimplifying to check that's the case. A `php` file in `"Photography/test.php"` that has `include("../included.php"); echo "\nSuccess";` and then a file at `"/included.php"` that just echos something like your example `echo "This worked";`

Comment: Wait a second, are you still including "photos.php" from within "index.php"? That would be an infinite loop, hence the error.

Comment: yeah I was. Now I see why there was an infinite loop and hence an error. Now that I deleted the linking of photos.php inside the index.php, it works like a charm now. Thank you!!

Comment: @GraceSawyer no dramas. As pointed out by @SeonggwonYoon, changing to `include_once()` prevents php from trying to repeat the loop.

Comment: Oh, that's what the include_once does, that should've been obvious by the name. Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

First check your directory

example >

```
<?php
    echo getcwd();
?>
//Running this code will tell you the current directory
```

and change to include(...)

example >

```
<?php
    include_once("...");
?>
<p>Hello, this is text from index.php</p>
```

Comment: @GraceSawyer "Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\Demonstration\Photography\photos.php on line 2" solve way is include change to include_once

Comment: This doesn't seem to work either. I tried doing that and copying the directory result into include() but it didn't recognize it. Then, I tried include("file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/Demonstration/index.php"), and it didn't work either. the file:///C.... directory used to work for linking images, but it doesn't work for php include either.

Comment: I tried "include_once" with the file:///... directory and it worked!  Thank you! It would be nice if you put include_once into your final answer. Not sure why it works, though...but thank you!!

Comment: That's cool other way is to go to the parent folder and use the folder you want.
Ex) include_once (../ "Photography / photos.php");

Comment: I tried include_once("../index.php") and that worked. Then I tried include("../index.php"), which is exactly what @Luke said, and it also worked!!  I tried his answer too before, it didn't work and now the same thing works all of a sudden...now I'm not sure which solution to use! Thanks so much, though...all of this makes sense now!

Answer (score 0):

if you use of direct address you have not problem NEVER..

```
include_once(addslashes(realpath($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'])).((DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR == '/') ? '/' : '\\\\')."Demonstration/Photography/photos.php");
```

AND

```
include_once(addslashes(realpath($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'])).((DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR == '/') ? '/' : '\\\\')."Demonstration/index.php");
```

and about patch in your hard disk

```
////defining CONST for recognition your Operation System  is windows or linux or mac USE / OR \....
define('DS', ((DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR == '/') ? '/' : '\\\\'));
define('_Site_PATH_', addslashes(realpath(dirname(__FILE__))) . DS );

include_once(_Site_PATH_."Demonstration".DS."Photography".DS."photos.php");
```